# Play sound in background

Tags: c#, audio

I have timer with an interval of 20 ms in Visual C#.

```
   public class Global
   {   
        //Global Vars
        public static System.Media.SoundPlayer sound = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(Project.Properties.Resources.tock);
   }

   private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        Global.sound.PlaySync();
   }
```

My tock.wav plays 70 ms. My Problem is that timer1_tick is waiting till the sound is played and I don't want to short my wav file. Is there any option to play the sound in the background? It might sounds not good, but I will give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

To start the SoundPlayer in a separate thread, simply call `Play()` instead of `PlaySync()`.

See [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Media.SoundPlayer_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) for reference.